# Skip parameters from package documentation without warning

Tags: r, package, documentation, roxygen2

I have created an `R` package and have set a generic with a few parameters having default values set to `NULL`. These parameters are not to be provided by the user and so I'd like to skip them from the documentation (using `roxygen2`) but not result in getting warnings in `R CMD check`.

An example:

```
#' Do that with myFoo...
#' 
#' `myFoo` ...
#' 
#' `myFoo` description...
#' 
#' @param object An object of myBar class
#' @param a A numeric value...
#' 
#' @return Smth
#' 
#' @name myFoo
#' @export
#' 
methods::setGeneric("myFoo", function(object, a, b=NULL, c=NULL) standard("myFoo"))


# User level
methods::setMethod(f="myFoo",
    signature=signature(object="myBar", a="numeric"),
    function(object, a, b, c){

            Some checks...

            b <- smth
            c <- smth

            return(myFoo(object@myBarItem, a, b, c))
    }
)


# For "iternal" use
methods::setMethod(f="myFoo",
    signature=signature(object="myBar2", a="numeric", b="character", c="matrix"),
    function(object, a, b, c){

            Smth

            return(someValue)
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addition of `@rdname` and `@aliases` have solved the issue, as it seems.

```
#' Do that with myFoo...
#' 
#' `myFoo` ...
#' 
#' `myFoo` description...
#' 
#' @param object An object of myBar class
#' @param a A numeric value...
#' 
#' @return Smth
#'
#' @name myFoo
#' @rdname myFoo
#' @export
#'
#' @aliases myFoo,myBar,numeric,ANY,ANY-method
#' myFoo,myBar2,numeric,character,matrix-method
#' 
#' @importFrom methods setGeneric setMethod
#'
methods::setGeneric("myFoo", function(object, a, b=NULL, c=NULL) standard("myFoo"))


# User level
methods::setMethod(f="myFoo",
    signature=signature(object="myBar", a="numeric"),
    function(object, a, b, c){

            Some checks...

            b <- smth
            c <- smth

            return(myFoo(object@myBarItem, a, b, c))
    }
)


# For "iternal" use
methods::setMethod(f="myFoo",
    signature=signature(object="myBar2", a="numeric", b="character", c="matrix"),
    function(object, a, b, c){

            Smth

            return(someValue)
    }
)
```